# ReDim in Subroutine VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub testCov()
    Rng2 = Sheets("20 Asset Model").Range("b3:f48")
    Dim covMatrix() As Variant
    ReDim covMatrix(1 To Rng2.Columns.Count, 1 To Rng2.Columns.Count)
    Call constructCovMatrix(Rng2, covMatrix)
    MsgBox (covMatrix)
End Sub

Sub constructCovMatrix(rng, ByRef covMatrix)
    '@rng The Range of the return series.

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            covMatrix(i, j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Covar(rng.Columns(i), rng.Columns(j))
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The code stops at the line ReDim, saying object missing. Why is this? Thanks

Comment: `Rng2 = Sheets("20 Asset Model").Range("b3:f48")` is an array and not a range. Try `Set Rng2 = Sheets("20 Asset Model").Range("b3:f48")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this to set your range as a range object be declaring it: (comments in-line)

```
Sub testCov()

    Dim Rng2 As Range '- Declare variable
    Set Rng2 = Sheets("20 Asset Model").Range("b3:f48") '-Set range
    Dim covMatrix() As Variant
    ReDim covMatrix(1 To Rng2.Columns.Count, 1 To Rng2.Columns.Count)
    Call constructCovMatrix(Rng2, covMatrix)
    MsgBox (covMatrix)

    Set Rng2 = Nothing '- Cleanup anytime 'Set' is used
End Sub
```

**Note:**

You may want to go to the VBA editor's setting sand click tools > options > Declare varible decleration > checked

This will ensure that you need to declare all your variables.

As is, the above code did not declare `Rng2` as a range. So when Excel first sees the name `Rng2` it creates a Variant type variable and sets it equal to the range of the sheet in the first line. Excel notices that `Sheets("20 Asset Model").Range("b3:f48")` is an array of cells, and it treats the variant `Rng2` as an array type variable going forward for the rest of your code. Assuming that you want to use the variable named `Rng2` as a range, we can declare it as such and use the `Set` command to assign it.

When you don't declare your variable types its easy for a mix-up like this to happen.

Comment: `You may want to go to the VBA editor's setting sand click tools > options > Declare varible decleration > checked` <--- I would say, since you have problems like this, you should ALWAYS use this setting.